# best practice for "freeze screen" while there are some operation (with progress bar ?)

Tags: android

Im a beginner in Android. I would like "freeze" my app (I mean, the user can't do any action) when I must do some operation.
By example, I delete all row of one my SQLiteBase's table..during this process, I would like show a progressbar  and the user can't do anything before the end.

I know (a little) the progressbar mechanism and the AsyncTask but I find it's a heavy solution.. there is a better simpler solution/practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, freezing is not a recommended thing and you should always try to allow the user to cancel or go back. It's annoying to wait for operations to finish. More info can be read [here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html).

However, sometimes when you must, you must...

In short, this is how you show a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
"dialog message", false);
```

(the "false" value is so that the user won't be able to cancel it using the back button)

Then, when you need to dismiss it (upon onPostExecute if you use an AsyncTask), you simply call :

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: So, I must use another thread ? (Asynctask..)
heavy solution...but if there is no choise..

Comment: It depends on what you do in the operation. If it's very fast anyway, why bother with the whole thing... If it's a long operation (depending how long, btw, as different length require different solutions), use a different thread since the UI thread will get stuck, not show a dialog and show the ANR to the user if it's about 5 seconds or so (plus it will be shown in case the user touches the screen during the operation).